# Log Creation/Altering of Tables By Envers Hibernate

Tags: java, mysql, spring, hibernate, hibernate-envers

1) When does Hibernate Envers create or alter the audit tables in the schema when there is a new Entity or column that is annotated with @Audited?

2) Is there a way to log the mysql commands that are called when there is a new audit table or column added?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> When does Hibernate Envers create or alter the audit tables in the schema when there is a new Entity or column that is annotated with @Audited?

Technically Hibernate Envers does not do this at all, this entire step is handled by Hibernate ORM proper.
During bootstrap of Hibernate ORM, the following steps occur:

1. ORM gathers all entity mappings, those defined in XML and annotated classes.  ORM takes all these representations and builds what we call a boot-model representation of the entities.
2. Envers implements a special hook that ORM calls into immediately after the boot-model has been prepared but before the runtime model is built which ORM uses thereafter.  This hook allows Envers to parse the boot-model in conjunction with the annotated java classes and it creates additional entity mappings for ORM that supplement what was built in (1).  These mappings are currently provided to ORM has additional Hibernate HBM XML mappings.
3. If the hook produces any additional HBM XML mappings, Hibernate ORM integrates those directly by converting them into boot-model representations as well.
4. Right before Hibernate ORM converts this boot-model into the runtime-model representation, ORM builds a database representation of the mappings.  It is at this point that the database model is used during the Schema Migration (if enabled) to validate/update/create the schema to match the database model representation.

> Is there a way to log the mysql commands that are called when there is a new audit table or column added?

There are several ways to accomplish this, some are easier than others of course.

For example, you could enable Hibernate SQL logging, configure those entries to be written to a special named file using your logging API of choice and then ship those logs off for post-processing on defined intervals.

You could also consider using something more standalone such as Debezium that is capable of monitoring database changes at the transaction/archive/oplog/binlog level and for certain connectors exposes a Kafka topic that specifically stores DDL changes.

Comment: Thank you for breaking down my question. This answer has everything. Much appreciated.

Comment: In addition to what Naros said, we recently did an extensive [blog post](https://debezium.io/blog/2019/10/01/audit-logs-with-change-data-capture-and-stream-processing/) on using Debezium/CDC for building audit logs. Feedback welcome!

Answer (score 0):

1. Hibernate-envers is using interceptors to insert changes into audition-tables. They are called right before the transaction is committed to the database.
2. The question is a little bit unclear, if you say mysql-commands I guess you mean update-queries like `CREATE TABLE` and `CREATE COLUMN`. By default, enver is reporting violations against the schema. I can imagine that - if you expose the audition-tables as hibernate-entitys aswell - a hbm2ddl might create those create-table and create-column update-queries.

After all I suggest to use the single-source-of-version-of-truth concept (SSOVOT) and failfast (FF) and dare the database as the single-point-of-faliure (SPOF).

### The wording problem

Yes, the hibernate-plugin is called enver, but from an scientific pov a enver(entity-version) is only the version-property marked with  `@Version` in the entity. The correct name is audition because you historically log all changes to the table in the database.

### In case of "change entity tables" having rows already.

First to say is that every payload-column in entity-tables is nullable, you must add a column in the audition-table it has by default a null value. But if the genuine table does not allow to have null-values in the colmn the audition is broken! This will lead to unexpected problems. This means that the automated replication of genuine-columns to audited-columns must be an process of reconstruct schema **AND DATA**.